# Passing Parmeters to an ASP.Net MVC2 Action from JQuery Autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-autocomplete

I'm passing 2 hardcoded parameters to an ASP.Net MVC2 Controller Action with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form#search_for_entity_user input#term").autocomplete({
            source: '<%= Url.Action("GetEntitySharedUsers", "Search") %>',
            delay: 200,
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $.post('<%= Url.Action("AddSharedUser", "Entity", new { id = "42", snlid="17394" }) %>',
                function (data) { })
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works fine, but now I need to change the values passed in in the $.post to come from my Model, so I'm thinking something like the following code, but that doesn't work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form#search_for_entity_user input#term").autocomplete({
            source: '<%= Url.Action("GetEntitySharedUsers", "Search") %>',
            delay: 200,
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $.post('<%= Url.Action("AddSharedUser", "Entity", new { id = '<%= Model.EntityId  %>', name= '<%= Model.Name  %>' }) %>',
                function (data) { })
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form#search_for_entity_user input#term").autocomplete({
            source: '<%= Url.Action("GetEntitySharedUsers", "Search") %>',
            delay: 200,
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $.post('<%= Url.Action("AddSharedUser", "Entity", new { id = Model.EntityId, name = Model.Name }) %>',
                function (data) { })
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

If it were me, though, I would extract that data so it is more semantic:

```
<input id="term" data-source-url="<%= Url.Action("GetEntitySharedUsers", "Search") %>" data-select-url="<%= Url.Action("AddSharedUser", "Entity", new { id = Model.EntityId, name = Model.Name }) %>" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var term = $("form#search_for_entity_user input#term");

        term.autocomplete({
            source: term.data('source-url'),
            delay: 200,
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $.post(term.data('select-url'), function (data) { });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```